# Redis with StackExchange.Redis client timing out randomly

Tags: .net, azure, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have a local copy of Redis installed on my windows 10 machine using the MSOpenTech build that I use during development. I'm trying to emulate an occasional timeout that we experience from our Azure Redis instance. A sample error I'm getting is:

> Additional information: Timeout performing GET 9f1cbfc9-07c3-4209-a7c4-07034d550766, inst: 0, mgr: ExecuteSelect, err: never, queue: 0, qu: 0, qs: 0, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 0, clientName: deployment29(504).API_IN_0, IOCP: (Busy=1,Free=999,Min=8,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=4,Free=32763,Min=8,Max=32767), Local-CPU: 100% (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/tree/master/Docs/Timeouts.md)

My connection to Redis looks like so:

```
    private static readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> LazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
    {
        var redisConfig = ConfigurationOptions.Parse(Resources.GetValueFromConfig(REDIS_CACHE_CONN_STRING));
        redisConfig.SyncTimeout = 3000;

        return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisConfig);
    });

    // As per Microsoft (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj131262), I am
    // initializing this once and reusing it.
    private static ConnectionMultiplexer _dataCacheFactory
    {
        get
        {
            return LazyConnection.Value;
        }
    }
```

My connection string looks like this for connecting to Azure:

```
<add key="RedisCacheConnString" value="xxxx.windows.net:xxxx,password=xxxxxxx=,ssl=True,abortConnect=False"/>
```

And this when connecting to the local MSOpenTech instance:

```
<add key="RedisCacheConnString" value="localhost:6379,abortConnect=False"/>
```

Additionally i've added minLoThreads of 50 to the app.config.

When doing an INFO cpu there doesn't seem to be any processor intensive requests. This is also confirmed that on our Azure Redis instance there doesn't appear to be any negative performance indicators.

```
# CPU
used_cpu_sys:12.36
used_cpu_user:1.17
used_cpu_sys_children:0.00
used_cpu_user_children:0.00
```

I should note that there is a very chatty front-end that can fire off up to 10 ajax requests at a time - almost all which hit redis, which I suspect could be an issue. I want to get to the bottom of why the timeouts are occurring.

Comment: I'm not clear with what your question is. And is it about Azure Redis or Redis from MSOpenTech, or StackExchange.Redis?

Comment: As you can see from the error i'm using the StackExchange.Redis client. This is used to connect to an azure instance (once deployed) or a local MSOpenTech instance (during development). I get the timeout on both instances.

Comment: Have you used ServiceStack.Redis to connect the local Redis or Azure Redis? Could you post your redis connection string which use 'xxxx' instead of the real hostname & password? I don't think the issue was caused by client library or server instance. The reason might be connection string with incorrect configuration parameters.

Comment: I've edited my initial post with the connection strings. Let me know if you see something awry with them.

I haven't tried ServiceStack.Redis, but would be open to it. I do really like the StackExchange port and would appreciate an understanding as to what i'm doing wrong in this regard.

Comment: It's important to notice that ServiceStack is a commercially-supported product. See the [free-quotas section](https://servicestack.net/download#free-quotas) on servicestack.net. Instead, StackExchange.Redis has no limitations and is under the MIT license.

Comment: Thanks @thepirat000 - that is a significant difference that I was not aware of.